# Python Tkinter - How to set the default value of a radiobutton?

Tags: python, tkinter

I've been searching for this a while, but no answers seemed to help me. So. I have this one RadioButton (actually three but don't worry about it) and I want to set the default value of it (the value which represents the unchecked box).

I've tried the "value" option but python doesn't recognize it. Here's what I have:

```
RadioButton1 = ttk.Checkbutton(frame2radio, text="Bold", width=20, cursor="hand2", underline=True, value=0)
```

Comment: P.S: How do I set the default value of a Combobox?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[ttk.Checkbutton documentation from NMT](http://infohost.nmt.edu/tcc/help/pubs/tkinter/web/ttk-Checkbutton.html)

"To change the state of a checkbutton through program control, use the .set() method of the associated control variable."

When you create your checkButton, add `variable=myVar` to the arguments. Then, when you want to select it, you can call `myVar.set(1)`.

Example:

```
RadioButton1 = ttk.Checkbutton(frame2radio, text="Bold", width=20, cursor="hand2", underline=True, value=0, variable=myVar)
myVar.set(1)
```

The button will represent this change on the next main window loop or when re-drawn.

---

If you wanted to do this in a Combobox, as mentioned in your comment, you can select a value from the combobox using the combobox's `.set(value)` function. Note that `value` has to be one of the options available in your Combobox.

Example:

```
myComboBox.set("Option 1")
```